# Using Jquery DatePicker output in SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, wordpress

I would like to allow users to filter custom wordpress post by date using Jquery Datapicker. I am basically letting users pick a date, store it into a variable ($Dt) and then pass that variable in an SQL query.

I am almost there, but for some reasons it won't work. I think this may be a format issue, but i have tried everything and nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: sqltuto
 *
 */

get_header();
?>

<script>
 $(function() 
 { 
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true,
      yearRange:"-100:+0",
      dateFormat:"dd MM yy"
     });
 });
</script>
  
  <div>

 <form name="frm1"  method="POST"> 
 
     <input type="text" name="txtDate" id="datepicker">
     <input type="submit" name="datepickers" value="search"> 
 
    </form>
 
 

  </div>
   //To display Entered Data 
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST["datepickers"]))
 {
     $Dt = $_POST["txtDate"];
 }
 ?>
<div>


<?php
global $wpdb;
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
 "
 SELECT wp_em_events.event_slug, wp_em_locations.location_latitude, wp_em_locations.location_longitude, wp_em_events.event_name, wp_em_events.event_start_time, wp_em_events.event_start_date, wp_em_events.event_rsvp, wp_em_events.event_attributes
 FROM wp_em_events
 INNER JOIN wp_em_locations
 ON wp_em_events.location_id=wp_em_locations.location_id
 WHERE wp_em_events.event_start_date='$Dt'
 
 
 
 
 ", ARRAY_A
);

?>
```

Many thanks for all your help!

Best,
Yvan

Comment: "It won't work" is quite the most useless problem description ever, what exactly does not work ? Does it get filtered but not the way you want ? Is the date invalid ? Does it return an error ?

Comment: How about `$Dt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['txtDate']));`?

Comment: Is the date column really in the same format as the js, or is it a date/timestamp column?

Comment: @Loufylouf - be nice.  While a frustrating problem description, we still should be nice.

Comment: This `WHERE wp_em_events.event_start_date='$Dt'` is where your problem is.  What format is `event_start_date`? It's almost certainly NOT the same as contained in your `$Dt` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your help and apologies for the lack of insights "loufylouf" (i am a newbie and not always able to articulate my thoughts). I simply had to change:

dateFormat:"dd MM yy"

to

dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"

Many thanks for all your help and time!

Best,
Yvan